# How is RMSD calculated in the Scipy implementation of the Kabsch algorithm?

Tags: scipy

Scipy calculates the rmsd like [this](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/e3cd846ef353b10cc66972a5c7718e80948362ac/scipy/spatial/transform/_rotation.pyx#L2381-L2383), and I'll paraphrase it here for convenience (for readability I drop the `weights` and the `max(*, 0)`)

```
rmsd = np.sqrt(np.sum(b ** 2 + a ** 2) - 2 * np.sum(s))
```

To me this does **not** look like RMSD.

Now from the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.align_vectors.html) one would infer that the `rmsd` return value is defined as the square root of double this expression:

[image]

The latter is indeed what I would consider to be the RMSD. In fact I went ahead and coded it up (note that this function expects me to apply the estimated transformation to one of the sets of points first whereas the snippet above does not)

```
def _calc_rmsd(a: np.ndarray, b_transformed: np.ndarray) -> float:
    distances = np.linalg.norm(a - b_transformed, axis=-1)
    rmsd = np.sqrt((distances ** 2).sum() / len(distances))
    return rmsd
```

I also plotted out what these would look like for randomly generated point pairs with normally distributed noise (blue is scipy, orange is mine)

[image]

Or extending the plot out to 200 point pairs:

[image]

So to sum it up:

- The definition of rmsd in the docs is in agreement with what I believe to be the widely accepted notion of rmsd
- The scipy code implementation of rmsd disagrees with the latter. I don't even understand what it's supposed to mathematically represent.
- From monte-carlo simulations, clearly the two implementations have different outcomes.

So what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the SciPy code is not returning the root-*mean*-squared distance. It sums the squared differences, but it does not divide by the number of vectors before taking the square root.  The difference between the SciPy calculation and yours is a factor of `sqrt(len(a))`.  You can verify this with an example such as the following.

```
In [157]: from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation

In [158]: def _calc_rmsd(a: np.ndarray, b_transformed: np.ndarray) -> float:
     ...:     distances = np.linalg.norm(a - b_transformed, axis=-1)
     ...:     rmsd = np.sqrt((distances ** 2).sum() / len(distances))
     ...:     return rmsd
     ...:
```

Some test data:

```
In [159]: a = np.array([[0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1.5], [2.0, -1.0, 4.0], [-1, 0, 5]])

In [160]: b = np.array([[0, 1, 1.5], [2, 2, 2], [1, -1, 5], [-3, 0.1, 1]])
```

Compute the rotation:

```
In [161]: R, rmsd = Rotation.align_vectors(a, b)

In [162]: rmsd
Out[162]: 3.8753534834716685
```

Here's your calculation of the RMSD:

```
In [163]: _calc_rmsd(a, R.apply(b))
Out[163]: 1.9376767417358356
```

And here is your calculation, multiplied by `sqrt(len(a))`, so it matches the result returned by `Rotation.align_vectors`:

```
In [164]: _calc_rmsd(a, R.apply(b)) * np.sqrt(len(a))
Out[164]: 3.875353483471671
```

This looks like a documentation issue.  If you have a moment, you could create a new issue for this over in https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues

Comment: Thanks! This solves my question. Wondering if you have any links/resources that show that the expression in the Scipy implementation works the way it does? I mean, we are adding the squared norm of all points in both sets then subtracting the sum of the singular values. How this relates to RMSD is lost on me.

Comment: FYI here's an issue I just posted https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/15907

Comment: I haven't worked through the algebra, but as far as I can tell, it works.

Comment: It certainly does. I redrew the plots with your correction and they line up.